# how to disable Application Bar Icon Button while processing other functions in windows phone application

Tags: c#, xaml, c#-4.0, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1

[reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rMNFx.jpg)

I have a code like below

```
private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){

(ApplicationBar.Buttons[0] as ApplicationBarIconButton).IsEnabled = false;

if (backstatus == false)
    {
    backstatus = true;
            myPopup.IsOpen = true;
            Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(delegate()
            {
        // some big code which take five minits to execute
    }
} }
```

At the time of  taping that button it is in enable mode. It will disable after execute hole the function.

But i need to disable it  while processing other functions.

Comment: can you be more clear about the scenario?

Comment: when i tap on save button it will take some time to save, while it is loading that button which i want to disable, is enable. after saving data that button is disable. But i want to disable that button before loading time.

Comment: [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rMNFx.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

You can use MVVM way and bind commands from your viewmodel to the applicationbar buttons. Or else, use await async for the long process instead of dispatcher.begininvoke()

Comment: I have used MVVM  for that function,

Comment: i used CustomerVM.SaveCustomer() function which is implemented in Customer View model class, in the Dispatcher